# number of points fixed by at least one non-trivial element

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $G$ be a permutation group that acts on (say) $X=\{1,2,...,n\}$. Is there a nice formula for the number of points of $X$ that are fixed by at least one non-trivial element of $G$? Of course, I mean some expression nicer than directly applying inclusion-exclusion to the sets of fixed points of nontrivial elements, since inclusion-exclusion seems to give a messy expression. Thanks!

Comment: So, the points with nontrivial stabilizer.

Comment: @arctic tern : Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an indication in the negative direction: the [cycle index polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index) $Z_G$ (which encodes how many permutations in the permutation group of each cycle type there are) is insufficient to determine how many points have trivial stabilizer. Here is an example of why - let

$A=\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$

$B=\{e,(12)(34),(12)(56),(34)(56)\}$

These are both copies of the Klein four group in $S_6$. The first is the usual copy within $S_4$, with $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$ acting on itself, and the second is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$ acting on $\mathbb{Z}_2\sqcup\mathbb{Z}_2\sqcup\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Both have cycle index polynomial $(z_1^6+3z_1^2z_2^2)/6!$, but two elements have trivial stabilizers in $A$ whereas zero elements have trivial stabilizers in $B$.

There might be some kind of inclusion-exclusion you can do with the [table of marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_ring#Marks), but I doubt you'll like it more that the inclusion-exclusion you were already talking about.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean to ask for a formula for a given abstract group. I was asking for a formula for a given concrete permutation group, in terms of its permutations.

Comment: @vgmath Okay, then pretend I didn't point out $A\cong B$. My point still stands: even if you know how many permutations of each cycle type there are, that's not enough to determine what you want. (Compare this with Burnside's lemma, which says just knowing the number of $1$-cycles in each permutation is enough to determine the number of orbits.)